# Apps-flyer's one link is not opens app if already installed?

Tags: ios, react-native, appsflyer, appsflyer-ios-sdk

```
appsFlyer.generateInviteLink(
            {
                channel: 'gmail',
                campaign: 'projecttest',
                customerID: 'ab8F',
                userParams: {
                    inviteCode: this.state.inviteCode,
                },
            },
            (link) => {
                console.log('appsFlyer link ', link);
            },
            (err) => {
                console.log(err);
            }
        );
```

I have done create appsflyer's deeplink by above method. When it triggered it opens in only browser. It could not open app if already installed.
What should I do?

Comment: Hi Sam009 . Please contact support@appsflyer.com and we'll be happy to assist you. Please attach your `AndroidManifest.xml` deep link configurations and the link that was generated using the `generateInviteLink` API

Comment: @BenjaminAF Im working on iOS. **[https://primecaptaintest.onelink.me/uz8F/49917c04]** this is the generated link.